# recursive solution to rock paper scissors

Tags: javascript, recursion

we went through this problem in a class today and I'm having trouble visualizing how the recursion is working exactly.  you are supposed to return an array of all possible combinations for n number of rock paper scissors, one player. with n =3, it would return an array of length 27.

I get the roundsLeft-1 parameter in the recursive call, but what's happening each time the function is called? Will really appreciate a high level explanation.  What I think is happening is:

the subroutine recursive function ignores the first element and then concatenates the next two. I'm failing to see how it arrives at all the solutions, and not just the ones with, for example, rock as the first element, and the last two concatenated on. :-/

```
var rockPaperScissors = function(numRounds) {
  var outcomes = [];
  var plays = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];

  // can add rounds later, get 3 working. 
  // for a three round game, it would be 3^3 = 27.
  // for any number of rounds it would be 3^numrounds. 

function findOutCome(roundsLeft, result){
  // when you cover all the rounds
  // push to the outcomes
  if (roundsLeft === 0) {
    outcomes.push(result);
    return;
  }

  plays.forEach(function(play){
    //result.push(play);
    //concat returns the entire array
    findOutCome(roundsLeft-1, result.concat(play))
  })
}

findOutCome(numRounds, []); // give it a starting point

return outcomes;
}


console.log(rockPaperScissors(3)); // returns an array of length 27
```

Comment: To imagine how recursion works imagine a value (ie. 4) then imagine the recursion being called the value times (4), now the 3rd recursion function has to take the result from the 4th, then the 2nd from 3rd and so on. Hence you always have to return a value Or another instance of the recursion (ie. return val == 0 ? 1 : recursion(val-1); ), Overall, just think in depth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var rockPaperScissors = function(numRounds) {
  var outcomes = [];
  var plays = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];

  // can add rounds later, get 3 working. 
  // for a three round game, it would be 3^3 = 27.
  // for any number of rounds it would be 3^numrounds. 

function findOutCome(roundsLeft, result){
  // when you cover all the rounds
  // push to the outcomes
  if (roundsLeft === 0) {
    outcomes.push(result);
    return;
  }

  plays.forEach(function(play){
    //result.push(play);
    //concat returns the entire array
    findOutCome(roundsLeft-1, result.concat(play))
  })
}

findOutCome(numRounds, []); // give it a starting point

return outcomes;
}


console.log(rockPaperScissors(3)); // returns an array of length 27
```

What is happening in the above is, before execution, we first define a large function with a function nested inside it.

Then we call `console.log(rockPaperScissors(3));` what this does is it calls our large function and assigns `numRounds=3`. Inside of our function body we find:

`var outcomes = [];` and `var plays = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];`.
These will remain defined for our recursive function to read `plays` and write to `outcomes`.

Then the nested function, which we will be using for recursion, gets defined.

Then finally our nested function gets called with: `findOutCome(numRounds, []);`

What this does is it calls our nested function for the first time and assigns `roundsLeft=numRounds` and `result=[].`

Our first recursion call looks like this:

`if (roundsLeft === 0){...}` this statement is false since roundsLeft is set to 3 so we move on...

`plays.forEach(function(play){...}` this loops 3 times since plays is set to `["rock", "paper", "scissors"]`.

The first loop `function(play){...}` is called with `play="rock"` and in the callback function body we call:

`findOutCome(roundsLeft-1, result.concat(play));`

What this does is it calls `findOutCome(2,result.concat("rock"))`

The usage of concat here does not modify the result array rather it works on a copy and concats `[]` with `"rock"` thus creating `["rock"]`.

If we wanted to actually modify the result array, we'd use `result.push(...)` here. 
But each recursion instance has its own local version of result so that wouldn't work since the changes wouldn't affect anything.

Our first recursion instance is still open and we're still inside our first forEach loop when we begin our recursion call.

Our 2nd recursion instance of `findOutCome` is called. In our 2nd instance `roundsLeft=2` and `result=["rock"]`.

`if (roundsLeft === 0) {...}` is false so we move onto our forEach loop...

We enter our first forEach loop and `play="rock"`. We then call `findOutCome(1, ["rock","rock"])`

We thus enter our 3rd level of recursion and set `roundsLeft=1` and `result=["rock","rock"]`.

`if (roundsLeft === 0) {...}` is still false so we move on...

We thus enter our 3rd level of our forEach loop which loops through our plays array... the first loop uses `play="rock"` thus our loop ends with:

`findOutCome(0,["rock","rock","rock"])`

We then enter our 4th recursion level and set `roundsLeft=0` and `result=["rock","rock","rock"]`.

`if (roundsLeft === 0) {outcomes.push(result);return;}` this statement is true so we process its logic.

our `outcomes` array which is currently set to `[]` gets appended with `["rock","rock","rock"]` thus creating:

`outcomes=[["rock","rock","rock"]];`

Then our if statement encounters `return` which ends our 4th recursion level and returns to our 3rd recursion level.

In our 3rd recursion level, we're still within our forEach loop, so we proceed to our 2nd element in the loop.

Remember, in our 3rd recursion level, our `findOutCome` function was called with `roundsLeft=1` and `result=["rock","rock"]` and wasn't modified. The variables are never modified rather each recursion instance uses its own local copy of these variables. Thus in our forEach loop, since it's the 2nd element being looped through, `play="paper"`.

We then encounter `findOutCome(roundsLeft-1, result.concat(play))` which evaluates to:

`findOutCome(0, ["rock","rock","paper"])`

We thus enter a 4th recursion level and `if (roundsLeft === 0) {outcomes.push(result);return;}` is true, preventing more than 3 recursion levels of depth, so we process its logic.

`outcomes.push(result)` appends `["rock","rock","paper"]` to our array.

Thus our outcomes array now reads: `outcomes=[["rock","rock","rock"],["rock","rock","paper"]];`

Then we encounter the `return` statement and close our 4th recursion level of depth and resume our 3rd recursion level's forEach loop.

By the time our forEach loop finishes in our 3rd level of recursion, `outcomes=[["rock","rock","rock"],["rock","rock","paper"],["rock","rock","scissors"]];`

Then our forEach loop finishes thus returning to our 2nd level of recursion's forEach loop where `roundsLeft=2` and `result=["rock"]`.

We proceed with our 2nd loop of our forEach for our 2nd recursion level of depth. `play="paper"`. Then we encounter:

`findOutCome(roundsLeft-1, result.concat(play))`

Thus creates a new 3rd level of depth with `roundsLeft=1` and `result=["rock","paper"]`.

The 3rd level goes through another forEach and sets `result=["rock","paper","rock"]` and `roundsLeft=0` sends it to a 4th level of depth.

Our result gets added to outcomes. Thus we now have:
`outcomes=[["rock","rock","rock"],["rock","rock","paper"],["rock","rock","scissors"],["rock","paper","rock"]];`

Etc and etc... ultimately our `outcomes` array grows to 27 elements in size and our first level of recursion which was called with `roundsLeft=3` and `result=[]`finishes its forEach loop. Finally we encounter `return outcomes;` and thus return our answer to `console.log(...)` which outputs our answer to the console. The console now shows an array containing 27 elements each of which contains an array 3 elements in size.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at function `findOutCome`:

```
function findOutCome(roundsLeft, result){
    // when you cover all the rounds
    // push to the outcomes
    if (roundsLeft === 0) {
        outcomes.push(result);
        return;
    }

    plays.forEach(function(play){
        //result.push(play);
        //concat returns the entire array
        findOutCome(roundsLeft-1, result.concat(play));
    });
}
```

you may notice that:

```
if (roundsLeft === 0) {
    outcomes.push(result);
    return;
}
```

means that the function will create a push another possiblity when `roundsLeft` reaches `0`.

Now let's look at `plays.forEach`:

```
plays.forEach(function(play){
    //result.push(play);
    //concat returns the entire array
    findOutCome(roundsLeft-1, result.concat(play));
});
```

where for each option in `plays` (`rock`, `paper`, `scissors`), the current result array being calculated starts with that option and then adds the result of:

```
findOutCome(roundsLeft-1, result.concat(play))
```

which means that we look back at `findOutCome` with one less round.

So say `3` was originally passed in:

```
1) `3 === 0` is `false` so we move on.
2) `plays.forEach` says take each option in `plays` (added to `result` which starts off empty) and pass it in to `findOutCome` with one round less. We pass in `Rock` as `result` and `2` as roundsLeft`:
    A) `2 === 0` is `false` so we move on.
    B) `plays.forEach` says do same as #2. We pass in [`Rock`, `Rock`] as `result` with `1` as `roundsLeft`.
        I) `1 === 0` is `false` so we move on.
        II) `plays.forEach says do same as #B. We pass in [`Rock`, `Rock`, `Rock`] as `result` with `0` as `roundsLeft`.
            Z) `0 === 0` is `true` so this time we add the `result` array we just got to the `outcomes` array.

    Now wait a second, we left off going through each `plays` in #B.  We need to repeat #I, #II, and #Z with the next option (after `rock`) in `plays`. Let's use `paper`. The result should be another array of ['rock', 'rock', `paper`] being pushed to `outcomes`.
```

Using the last option `scissors` (with steps #I, #II, and #III should result in the [`rock`, `rock`, `scissors`] array being added to `outcomes`.

Now wait, we were also in middle of doing this whole process where `roundsLeft` is `2`. We just did it for `rock`. Let's repeat #A and #B for second option `paper`. Then repeat `roundsLeft` at `1` where the `plays.forEach` adds all the possibilities #I, #II, and #Z when we are at [`rock`, `paper`. This will add another three arrays to `outcomes`:

```
[`rock`, `paper`, `rock`]
[`rock`, `paper`, `paper`]
[`rock`, `paper`, `scissors`]
```

Then we can run third option where `roundsLeft` is `2` and add another three arrays to `outcomes`:

```
[`rock`, `scissors`, `rock`]
[`rock`, `scissors`, `paper`]
[`rock`, `scissors`, `scissors`]
```

Now, wait we in middle of going through each of `plays` and adding `9` possible arrays to `outcomes`. We started at [`rock`. Let's add another `9` at [`paper` and another `9` at [`scissors`.

That gives us the `27` possible combinations we were looking for.

As `roundsLeft` starts off bigger, the bigger the layers within which we run all of this grows, allowing us to take care of all of those growing possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

To understand recursion, you have to understand functions scope. To keep things simple enough to be understood, let's say that the curly brackets that define the beginning and end of the function block (body) represent its scope and that scope can be illustrated by a box. Just visualize a box.
Now, every time a function is declared, it comes as box.
A function can be called using external code or internal code (recursion). So if you invoke a function inside itself (or another function) that function comes as a child box located inside the parent box. You can pass parameter(s) to a function, but the parameters only know the value that it passed to it. so any changes applied to the parameter should not affect an external variable with the same name as the parameter. that being said, lets go back to your question, and try to explain the results using our box analogy.

for what follows, we will use boxes of different colors (red, green, yellow, white). Remember that the boxes illustrate the various scopes. Also "rock" is "r", "paper" is "p", "scissor" is "s".

On the first invocation of 'findOutcome' a RED box is created and contains parameters roundleft = 3. result=[].

```
//RED BOX : roundleft = 3, result =[]
//----for each rock, paper, scissor
//start with rock (r)  -- note : 3 , r means "roundleft, rock"
3 , r  => internal call to findOutcome() creates a GREEN BOX, 
          so that GREEN BOX is inside the RED one,
          with decremented roundleft value 2.
          Keep in mind that parameter only knows about its value

 //GREEN BOX : roundleft = 2, result =[r]
 //-----for each r p s,
 //starts with rock, 
 2 , r  => internal call to findOutcome() creates a YELLOW BOX,
           inside the GREEN BOX which is inside the RED BOX
           with decremented roundleft value 1.

  //YELLOW BOX : roundleft 1, result =[r, r]
  //----- for each r p s, 
  //starts with rock, roundleft =1, result =[r, r]
  1, r  => internal call to findOutcome() creates a WHITE BOX
           with decremented roundleft value 0.
           at this point RED > GREEN > YELLOW > WHITE

    //WHITE BOX: round = 0, result =[r, r, r]
    roundsLeft = 0 => push result to outcomes. 
                      return means exit WHITE BOX. 
                      we are now (back) inside YELLOW BOX 
                      where roundl= 1, res=[r, r] 
                      is there another element to go through? YES : "paper"

  //follow with paper, roundleft =1, result =[r, r]
  1,  paper(p) // internal call creates a WHITE BOX

    //WHITE BOX: round 0, result =[r, r, p]
    0 => push result to outcomes.
         exit white box, back to YELLOW BOX
         is there another element to go through? YES : "scissor"

  //follow with scissor. roundleft =1, result =[r, r]
  1, scissor // internal call creates a WHITE BOX

    //WHITE BOX: roundl 0, result =[r, r, s]
    0 => push result to outcomes.
         exit WHITE BOX, back to YELLOW BOX
         is there another element to go through? NO =>exit YELLOW BOX
         back inside GREEN BOX where roundl 2, result =[r]

 /*------ at this point outcomes length = 3 ---------- */


 //GREEN BOX (is inside RED BOX)
 //is there another element to go through? YES : "paper"

 //follow with paper, roundleft =2, result =[r]
 2, p  // internal call creates a YELLOW BOX
  //----- for each r p s, 
  //starts with rock, roundleft =1, result =[r, p]
  1, r // internal call creates a WHITE BOX

    //WHITE BOX: roundl 0, result =[r, p, r]
    0 => push result to outcomes. 
         exit WHITE BOX  and back inside YELLOW BOX 
         where roundl= 1, res=[r, p] 
         is there another element to go through? YES : "paper"

  //follow with paper, roundleft =1, result =[r, p]
  1, p   // internal call creates a WHITE BOX inside the YELLOW

    //WHITE BOX: roundl 0, result =[r, p, p]
    0 => push result to outcomes.
         exit WHITE BOX, back to YELLOW BOX
         is there another element to go through? YES : "scissor"


  //follow with scissor. roundleft =1, result =[r, p]
  1, s  // internal call creates a WHITE BOX

    //WHITE BOX: roundl 0, result =[r, p, s]
    0 => push result to outcomes.
         exit WHITE BOX, back to YELLOW BOX
         is there another element to go through? NO =>exit YELLOW BOX
         back inside GREEN BOX where roundl 2, result =[r]

 /*------ at this point outcomes length = 6 --------*/


 //GREEN BOX (inside the RED BOX)
 //is there another element to go through? YES : "scissor"

 //follow with scissor, roundleft =2, result =[r]
 2, s
  //----- for each r p s, 
  //starts with rock, roundleft =1, result =[r, s]
  1, r

    //WHITE BOX: roundl 0, result =[r, s, r]
    0 => push result to outcomes. 
         exit WHITE BOX  and back inside YELLOW BOX
         where roundl= 1, res=[r, s] 
         is there another element to go through? YES : "paper"

  //follow with paper, roundleft =1, result =[r, s]
  1, p 

    //WHITE BOX: roundl 0, result =[r, s, p]
    0 => push result to outcomes.
         exit WHITE BOX, back to YELLOW BOX
         is there another element to go through? YES : "scissor"


  //follow with scissor. roundleft =1, result =[r, s]
  1 s // decrement to 0

    //WHITE BOX: roundl 0, result =[r, p, s]
    0 => push result to outcomes.
         exit WHITE BOX, back to YELLOW BOX
         is there another element to go through? NO =>exit YELLOW BOX
         back inside GREEN BOX where roundl 2, result =[r]

 /*------ at this point outcomes length = 9 --------------*/


 //GREEN BOX : is there another element to go through after scissor ? 
 //    NO =>exit GREEN BOX
 //back inside RED BOX where roundl 3, result =[]

// RED BOX
//is there another element to go through after rock? YES : "paper"
//start with paper
3, p  // internal call creates a GREEN BOX

 //GREEN BOX : roundl 2, result =[p] 
 //-----for each r p s,
 //starts with rock, 
 2, r   // internal call creates a YELLOW BOX

  //YELLOW BOX : roundl 1, result = [p, r]
  //----- for each r p s, 
  //starts with rock, roundleft =1, result =[p, r]
  1, r   // internal call creates a WHITE BOX

    //WHITE BOX: roundl 0, result = [p, r, r]
    0 => push result to outcomes. 
         exit WHITE BOX and back inside YELLOW BOX
         where roundl= 1, result = [p, r] 
         is there another element to go through? YES : "paper"

  //follow with paper, roundleft =1, result =[p, r]
  // ... and so on...
```

And so on until we're back again to the RED BOX and outcomes length will go from 9 (rock) to 18 ( on paper) to 27 ( on scissor).
So basically, in recursion a function is called internally and every time a new scope is created. The same block of code is executed, each time with parameters that only know about their values and therefore do not affect outside of the scope (box). when hitting the bottom of the box, if there is no internal call of the function, it returns to the parent box (one level up).
My native language is french, so hopefully my english is not that rusty and this box analogy helped you understand how recursion works.